# Como utilizar a expressão .SqlQuery do EF no EFCore?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estou refatorando um código e estou com essa dúvida.

```
public class MovimentoManualListRepository : RepositoryBase<MovimentoManualList>, IMovimentoManualListRepository
{
    ConsultarContext _context;
    public MovimentoManualListRepository(ConsultarContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<MovimentoManualList> Listar()
    {
        return _context.Database
            .SqlQuery<MovimentoManualList>("ListarMovimentacao")
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Acabo recebendo tal erro:

> Error CS1061: 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução foi utilizar o metodo .FromSql para executar a procedure.

```
public class MovimentoManualListRepository : RepositoryBase<MovimentoManualList>, IMovimentoManualListRepository
    {
        ConsultarContext _context;
        public MovimentoManualListRepository(ConsultarContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<MovimentoManualList> Listar()
        {
            return _context.MovimentoManualLists
                .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.ListarMovimentacao")
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Além de criar uma nova propriedade no meu contexto

```
public DbQuery<MovimentoManualList> MovimentoManualLists { get; set; }
```